# How can I access data beyond the 128th byte after a DCPA DPL seek/get operation?

Tags: mks

I have a program which needs to work with images, and in order to do so it reads the image metadata from a text file; the metadata is fixed-length and consistently encoded in the following manner:

- 001-099: Folder
- 100-198: Filename
- 199-206: Width
- 207-214: Height
- 215-215: Newline

The metadata is stored in the user folder with the same filename as the data file. I am able to access this data easily enough with the following field edit:

```
note ** The SEEKTEST stdjob has a Record Size of 215 bytes.
define|port $var01/SEEKTEST//$01.
move <filename> to $var01.
open $01|rd.

seek $01 0 0 else
  pause "Unable to access metadata file";
  stop.

get $01 else
  pause "End of file; terminating";
  stop.

pause $01@01@.

close $01.
stop.
```

This works as expected; it shows all 215 bytes of the retrieved record so the data is obviously being read according to the SEEKTEST record size.

However, whenever I try to access any bytes past 128, it gives me an invalid substring error. For example:

```
note ** This shows the folder, as expected.
pause $01@01:001-099@.

note ** This doesn't show the filename, just throws an invalid substring error.
pause $01@01:100-198@.
```

Is there any way to work with the rest of the data in this field? Mostly, I'm just looking for a way to copy the subfields into declared variables that can be handled like normal.